# How to use placeholders in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there a way to use placeholders in JSON similar to the Java properties file?

I would like to replace the following property values with the JSON strings shown below. If it is possible to use placeholders, how would I be able to dynamically replace the placeholders using JS or JQuery? It would be great if this can be done without using Regex match and replace.

```
WelcomeMessage=Welcome {0}
GoodBye=Goodbye,{0}. Thank you for visiting {1}
```

JSON string

```
   { "messages" : {
                  "WelcomeMessage":"Welcome {name}",
                  "GoodBye":"Goodbye,{name}. Thank you for visiting {siteName}"
                 }
    }
```

Comment: The JSON string format may not be correct I am just using it as an example.

Comment: Are you looking to do this for some form of templating?

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
// Your messages
var message = {
    'welcome': 'Welcome {name}'
} ;

// Your variables
var vars= {
    'name': 'user'
};


var placeholders = function ( message, variables ) {
    for ( var v in variables ) {
        message = message.replace( '{'+v+'}' , variables[v] );
    }

    return message;
} ;

alert ( placeholders(message['welcome'], vars) );
// Alert: Welcome user
```